# How do I move application data from one Mac account to another?

Tags: mac, settings, accounts

I'd like to move my kids applications to a separate account but am trying to figure out the best way to move the application data.  For example, are documents and settings stored somewhere consistently on a Mac or do I need to use some sort of migration assistant?

Answer (score 1):

The migration assistant makes it very easy to move a whole account. You could then make an applications folder in their account (before or after the migration) to contain the apps you only want to be seen by them.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way just to migrate certain apps to a new account without having to move/copy the whole account?

Comment: It really depends on the apps. You can certainly research where each app stores it's data and move those files, but in my experience, it's so much faster to just bring the entire account over. You can delete all the apps that came faster than telling the mac not to copy them. The extra "user data" lies unused - you can clean it, but why bother. Most application data files are of inconsequential size and hidden away from view in ~/Library